# Checkboxes have wrong values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

My goal is to check `<mat-checkbox>`, if `serviceIsSelected` is true.

I have 3 checkboxes in 2 tables:

```html
@for (service of dataSource; track dataSource; let index = $index) {
  <table mat-table *ngIf="dataSource && dataSource[index]" [dataSource]="dataSource[index]" formArrayName="services">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      Index: {{index | json}}, Value: {{services.at(index).get('serviceIsSelected')?.value | json}}
      <mat-checkbox formControlName="serviceIsSelected"></mat-checkbox>
```

This is the output, when I load the page:

[image]

They also behave strangely when I check or uncheck them. See:

[image]

This is how I set the FormControl:

```js
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

private createForm(quotationView: QuotationView): void {
    const serviceFormGroup = this._formBuilder.array<FormGroup>([]);

    quotationView.services.forEach((service: Service, index: number) => {
      service.serviceIsSelected = service.typeOfService === 'optional';

      // Add additional property to the form
      const amountValue: number = (service.allowsMultipleServices && service.defaultAmount) ? service.defaultAmount : 1;
      const groupOfServices = this._formBuilder.group({
        ...service,
        serviceIsSelected: new FormControl({ value: service.serviceIsSelected, disabled: service.typeOfService === 'mandatory' })
      });

      serviceFormGroup.push(groupOfServices);
    });

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      services: serviceFormGroup,
      // More FormControls
    } as QuotationViewForm);
   
  }
```

If I check or uncheck a checkbox, I see that `this.form.value` returns

```json
{
    "services": [
        {
            "serviceIsSelected": false
        },
        {
            "serviceIsSelected": true
        },
        {
            "serviceIsSelected": false
        }
    ],
}
```

which is always correct.

What is the issue that is not making the checkboxes work correctly and how can I fix it?

Comment: try change the variable "index" by another one, e.g. called indexTable `@for (service of dataSource; track dataSource; let indexTable = $index) {..`.

Comment: @Eliseo I tried that. Still the same issue.

Comment: try to access the index by i, not the index
Index: {{ i | json}}, Value: {{services.at(i).get('serviceIsSelected')?.value | json}}